# How to connect the socket.io with backend

Tags: c#, angularjs, ionic-framework, socket.io

I am trying to implement chat in my ionic project what i have tried so far is to connect the socket.io with my backend (c#) is below.

Here is my index.html

```
<script src="http://192.xxx.x.xxx:8888/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

and here i created socketservice.js file looks like

```
 var example = angular.module('starter.socketService',[])

    example.service('SocketService',function(socketFactory){
        console.log("SocketService");
            return socketFactory({

                ioSocket: io.connect('http://192.xxx.x.xxx:8888')


            });
            console.log(socketFactory);
        })
```

finaly i created a folder called server i have a chat-server.js file in there.

```
var io = require('socket.io')(8888);
  console.log(io);
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log(socket);

    socket.on('send:message', function(msg){
        console.log(msg);
        socket.emit('message', msg);
        console.log("success");
    });

});
```

**ERROR:**

> GET http://192.xxx.x.xxx:8888/socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

What i have done worng is there anything i have to do to connect with server always i am getting this error

Can some one tell me step by step explaination in c# to develop for socket.io

Comment: Are you sure chat-server.js is running in the background? Something along the lines of `$ node chat-server.js` in your terminal.

Comment: @MohanGopi If you are very sure about the code, the problem would be with the server port. Could you try porting the server ip from 8888 to 80 and try once as usually all port except 80 port will be blocked.